# c# При добавлении затираются данные и остается только последнее введенное значение

Tags: xml, datatable

НЕ работает. Добавляю данные в textbox. Жму кнопку. Данные сохраняются. Открываю xml, а в нем только последнее значение.
Где ошибка, подскажите?

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // НЕИЗВЕСТНО РАБОТАЕТ
        {
             // таблица
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.TableName = "SearchWords"; // название таблицы
                dt.Columns.Add("word"); // название колонки
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                // добавляем строки
                DataRow row = ds.Tables["SearchWords"].NewRow();
                row["word"] = textBox4.Text;
                ds.Tables["SearchWords"].Rows.Add(row);

                // сохраняем
                ds.WriteXml("D:\\Words.xml");
        }
```

В xml нужна только одна колонка с введенными данными word

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <SearchWords>
    <word>111111111</word>
  </SearchWords>
</NewDataSet>
```

И подскажите как сделать xml вот так:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <SearchWords>
    <word>888888</word>
    <word>22</word>
    <word>11111</word>
    </SearchWords>
</NewDataSet>
```

А с текущим кодом получается вот так (т.е. много лишних тегов):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <SearchWords>
    <word>888888</word>
  </SearchWords>
  <SearchWords>
    <word>22</word>
  </SearchWords>
  <SearchWords>
    <word>11111</word>
  </SearchWords>
 </NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Чтобы получить желаемый xml, придётся отказаться от DataSet/DataTable. Используйте, например, LinqToXml. Но это уже тема для другого вопроса, лучше задать его отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все объекты новые, созданы в `button12_Click`. Как они узнают о текущем содержимом "D:\Words.xml"?

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

  if (System.IO.File.Exists("D:\\Words.xml"))
  {
    ds.ReadXml("D:\\Words.xml");
  }
  else
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = "SearchWords"; // название таблицы
    dt.Columns.Add("word"); // название колонки
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
  }
  // добавляем строки
  ...
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите объяснения, почему работает "у индуса на видео"? Я не знаю индуса и не видел видео. Я объяснил почему код, который Вы привели, делает то, что делает.